How to Handle Firebase Password Reset Links in Flutter with app_links?
I am building a Flutter app that uses Firebase for authentication, and I need to implement a password reset functionality. I want to handle the Firebase-generated password reset links (deep links) using the app_links package.
Here's what I am trying to achieve:
The user requests a password reset.
Firebase sends an email with a reset link (containing oobCode as a query parameter).
When the user clicks the link, the app should:
Open automatically (if installed).
Extract the oobCode parameter from the URL.
Navigate to a reset password screen where the user can enter a new password.
I have tried the following code to handle deep links:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:app_links/app_links.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DeepLinkHandler {
  static final AppLinks _appLinks = AppLinks();
  static StreamSubscription<Uri>? _linkSubscription;

  static Future<void> handleAppLink(BuildContext context) async {
    _linkSubscription = _appLinks.uriLinkStream.listen((uri) {
      debugPrint('Deep link received: $uri');
      _processDeepLink(context, uri);
    });

    final Uri? initialLink = await _appLinks.getInitialLink();
    if (initialLink != null) {
      debugPrint('Initial deep link: $initialLink');
      _processDeepLink(context, initialLink);
    }
  }

  static void _processDeepLink(BuildContext context, Uri uri) {
    if (uri.host == 'example.firebaseapp.com' || uri.host == 'example.web.app') {
      final oobCode = uri.queryParameters['oobCode'];
      if (oobCode != null) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResetPasswordScreen(oobCode)),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  static void dispose() {
    _linkSubscription?.cancel();
  }
}

Problems:
The app does not open when the reset link is clicked.
app_links does not seem to recognize the deep links correctly.
I am not sure if the Firebase deep links are set up correctly in my project.
I created a web page that sends the user back to the application to reset the password. resetPage

Firebase dynamic links should open your app if you have configured it correctly with the correct listeners.

Firebase dynamic links is deprecated and starting from August 25, 2025, that's why I tried with firebase hosting but I didn't find a solution and I have no idea how I should modify the AndroidManifest.xml file

Either you can try an alternative with this: https://app.urlgeni.us/
Or you need to setup your own server that will open your app when user clicks on a specified url. Using app_links package in flutter is the way to go but you need to upload two different sort of json file in your server which will automatically open your app when user clicks a link from an email and you want to open your app instead of the browser.
